# Under what conditions is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that assymptotes to a straight line a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, geometric-topology

In the usual topology.
In particular, is the graph of the function $f: (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x) = \tan(x)$, closed?

edit: in the generic case is already clear for me that it is not, for example, the graph of $f(x) = e^{-x}, x>0$. But still, I'm curious about the particular case above. Or something like the graph of $e^x$, on the entire line.

Comment: Yes.  Show the complement is open.

Comment: I know that the graph of continuous functions on compact sets are closed, so the restriction of this function to $[-pi/2 + 1/n, pi/2 - 1/n]$ is closed. I was thinking about using properties of convergence of functions. Still, your comment wasn't too helpful - if I knew how to show that the complement is closed, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the graph of a continuous function over a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

To show this, suppose $f : C \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $(x_n, f(x_n)) \to (x, y)$. Then $x_n \to x$. Since $C$ is closed, we have $x \in C$. Since $f$ is continuous on $C$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. But $f(x_n) \to y$ too, since $(x_n, f(x_n)) \to (x, y)$. Therefore, by uniqueness of limits, $y = f(x)$, hence $(x, y)$ is in the graph of $f$.

Try thinking of counterexamples where $C$ is not closed, or when $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: I already devised a conterexample. Your comment was very helpful and answered a good deal of the question. Still, I'm worried about the paticular case mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of  $$f: (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$$ where $$ f(x) = tan(x)$$ is closed.

As you know the complement of the graph is the union of two open sets, thus the graph is closed.

The fact that a function has an asymptote does not prevent the graph to be closed.

Similarly the graph of $$ f(x)=e^x $$ on the entire real line is closed.

Comment: In fact, the complement of this set seems to me to be an open set (or seemed, now I got a nice proof of it - in the answer I posted), but I don't know how to show that it is open. In fact, I can't even describe it in any way other than "the complement of the graph".

Comment: Well, it has two open component. One to the right of the graph and one to the left of the graph. You can prove the openness by showing that for each point you have an open ball centered at the point which is entirely contained in the complement. Forget about the asymptotes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it for the graph of $tan(x)$. Suppose $(x_n, tan(x_n)) \in Graph(f)$.
If $x_n \to \pi/2$ or $x_n \to -\pi/2$, then the sequence $(x_n, f(x_n))$ is not convergent. Therefore, a convergent sequence $(x_n, f(x_n))$ in the curve is such that $(x_n)$ converges to $x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, so $x \in [-\pi/2 + 1/n, \pi/2 - 1/n]$ for some $n$ and, therefore, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.